# With TypeScript, is there a way to determine the element type of an empty array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've built a component called `SelectPlus` that offers the functionality its name suggests.

Here's a critical part of how its props are typed:

```
interface ISelectPlus {
  itemList: Array<string> | Array<Object>;  // Either a simple string array or a more complex object array; if the latter then `objectMap` must be provided
  values?: string | Array<string> | null;   // Contains either a single string value or an array of them; the latter for the multiple case
  objectMap?: ObjectMap;                    // Provides translation of any object array to `key`, `text`, and optionally `parentId` - ex. {key: 'id', text: 'displayLabel', parentId: 'parent'}
}
```

As I do with all of my custom, reusable React components, I do initial checking to help [future] me and other developers remember what properties are required.  So, for example, if `itemList` is of type `Array<Object>` then an `objectMap` must be provided.  The component is rendered in a red error state with a message about the missing `objectMap` if it's not provided.

What I'm wondering is if the calling function has clearly typed `itemList` as `Array<Object>`, but the array is still empty, is there a way to determine this within the `SelectPlus` component?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to default to treating it as `string` or `Object`. Also, please don't use `Object` as a type. Use `object` (which is still pretty ehhhh), or a more specific object type.

Comment: An empty array can have any element type whatsoever; there's no principled way to say that `[]` is *not* a `string[]`.  Why do you need this?  Can't you flip your check so that the presence of `objectMap` determines what type `itemList` is?

Comment: That is, doesn't [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6Rxw) suffice for your check?  An empty array is fine no matter what; only a non-empty array could cause a validation error

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `Object` type ? You almost never need to use this type, it is a constructor type. If you want to type an any object, you can use `Record<string, unknown>`